# Deliver messages in order based on xml content in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have a problem where I receive files from a third party via a website. These files come in order from the third-party and sit in a folder. Because of security constraints, I am not able to poll the directory directly via SMB but instead I have to fetch the files every 1 minute using SFTP. This creates a problem because the files that were delivered to me in-order are now all together in my receive location's folder. I need to deliver these files in the order they came to my send port.

I have thought of creating a separate program that would open the files and then copy them in order (based a segment called SequenceId in the XML) to a folder within the BizTalk server that is monitored by the receive location which would ensure the files are delivered in order. I would prefer not to introduce another failure point (the program) but I am not sure how I can do this with pure BizTalk.

Comment: Have a look at the tutorials on the biztalk convoy pattern. I think it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure BizTalk (search for BizTalk resequencing), however you end up with a complex solution including a singleton Orchestrations and it is usually easier to use a database table.

1. First interface picks it up, and just insert the data into a table.  Either as flat table if your message structure is flat, or as a one field with XML data and another field that contains your sequence number extracted from the payload.
2. Your second interface polls a stored procedure that looks if the next in sequence is available to be processed.

You will have to have considerations about what to do if a particular message for a sequence never arrives, do you send out an alert, or process the messages you do have after a preset delay.